# respond_to block always renders html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

Until now, my team has used HTTP requests to create and modify a specific ActiveRecord object in our project. The related controller methods only render as json:

```
render json: { json: 'goes here' }
```

I'm creating a basic CRUD interface to do this, which should render an HTML page (`render :html`) however, we also have a secondary API that relies on being able to call these controller actions through HTTP requests and get a json response back.

I've tried using a `respond_to` block as follows to achieve this:

```
respond_to do | format |
    format.json { render json: { json: 'goes here' } }
    format.html # Appropriate view
end
```

However, even with direct HTTP requests (tested using cURL in a terminal), I always get an HTML response back. I've tried using a `constraint` in the routes file, but not even that can get a JSON response to come out.

Is there something more I need to do, either on the server or client side, in order to get a JSON response from HTTP requests, while still rendering the appropriate view when the request comes from a form? Thank you!

Comment: Rails determines the desired response format from the HTTP Accept header submitted by the client. Are you sure you pass the correct value to your headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the output from `rake routes` then you'll see all your URIs have this `(.format)` suffix to them. The parens mean that it's optional. If not provided (and if the `Accept` header(s) don't disambiguate the request) then Rails defaults to responding with HTML.

So in your cURL command just provide the `.json` format and Rails will respond with the right thing:

```
curl localhost:3000/foos.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a particular format, e.g json, so you need to pass that in the params from where the request is coming, with the key value: `format`

```
whatever_path(format: :json)
```

Comment: I wish I could give you both the correct answer. This will help any time I need to make the request in the Rails code, but @smathy's answer helps in the use case the question describes.

Comment: No problem mate. You got the right answer, that's it :)